# Cleric spells using Holy Symbols as a focus requiring material components

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, spell-components

p203 of the 5e PHB indicates that

> A character can use a component pouch or spell casting focus in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell...

So, if I'm starting out as a Knowledge Domain cleric, I get *Identify* as a level 1 Domain spell - normally this requires "A pearl worth at least 100 gp and an owl feather."

I'm assuming that a holy symbol would stand in in place of the feather, but I still need the pearl to cast?

Comment: Hello Sparemeister! Welcome to the site! You should [take the tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance to get acquainted with the stack and earn a free badge. I've updated you question tags to include the system that you are using. You should do the same for any future questions you have. That way, the site can sort the question more effectively and you won't have to include that info in the question body or title.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes.**  Your question includes the relevant rule.  You'll need to keep that 100gp pearl around, once you can afford it.  Note that material components aren't consumed by a spell unless it says that they are, so you'll only have to buy it once.